# Select records from start of month to current date

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, dateadd, datepart

I'm trying to select records that were added to the database between the start of the current month and the current day - I more or less know how to get records from the current day, and within a specific time period - but how do I get it so it starts from the beginning of the current calendar month?

Comment: Are there going to be rows that represent data in the future, and you need to leave those out? Or is it sufficient to just say >= beginning of month?

Comment: It's sufficient to just say >= beginning of month. Basically I'm doing a tally/sum on certain records from the start of the month to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sm DATETIME;
SET @sm = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()));

SELECT columns 
    FROM dbo.foo 
    WHERE datetime_column >= @sm;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE YEAR([Date])=YEAR(GETDATE())
AND MONTH([Date])=MONTH(GETDATE())
AND DAY([Date])<=DAY(GETDATE())
```

Comment: I hope there's no index on the [Date] column, because it's wasted here. It is quite expensive to extract the datepart information and it will always lead to a scan.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from YourTable
where DateCol >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're doing here is Getting the Month, appending '/01' and then appending the year.  Casting it as a string to handle the appending, then casting it as a DateTime.

So it's a little bit more involved than doing any sort of date math, but it's readable I think.

```
DECLARE @firstOfMonth DATETIME
SET @firstOfMonth = CAST(CAST(DATEPART(mm, GetDate()) as varchar) + '/01/' + cast(DATEPART(yyyy, Getdate()) as varchar) as datetime)

WHERE DateToCheck BETWEEN @firstOfMonth and GetDate()
```

Comment: Be careful about this because your mm/dd/yyyy format won't register correctly in certain languages/regional settings. Much safer to use ISO standard "unbreakable" formats (e.g. YYYYMMDD) or not wasting energy converting to a string in the first place. :-)

Comment: I agree converting to string is a waste but this always seemed more readable to me, than doing the DateMath

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DateToCheck > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d673/2/0