# INTERVAL 1 MONTH not working With symfony2 doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am stuck here and i spend last 2 days resolving this issue but failed. I am writing a query inside my repository to get the entries for current month. here is my query:-

```
$this->getEntityManager()
 ->createQuery('SELECT count(a) FROM CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance a where a.student_id='.$id.'
 and a.date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
```

When I try to run this it gives me an error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 133: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_COMMA, got '1'
```

Even I tried [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672125/how-to-make-doctrine-expression-doctrine-1-2-try-to-get-last-7-days) but didn't helped me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use parameter binding:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT count(a) FROM CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance a where a.student_id = :id and a.date > :date');
$query->setParameter('id', $id);
$query->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('-1 month'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jkucharovic. It was so usefull. Can u plese tell me how can i do the same with INTERVAL 1 YEAR

Comment: `$query->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('-1 year'));`

Comment: and can u tell how can i use NOW here

Comment: :- Can u tell me the both.. NOW() and TODAY

Comment: _Now_ is simple – `$query->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));`. But it's not usable, because it means “at this moment”.

Comment: For use _Today_ you need to change your query to `SELECT … AND a.date >= :today AND <= :now` and parameters 
`$query->setParameter('today', new \DateTime('today')); $query->setParameter('now', new \DateTime('now'));`

Comment: :- Sorry to disturb u again Sir, U know I am stuck again the same place. I want to fetch data from the first day of the month to current date. and also from first day of year to current date. How can i do it in doctrine. Sql does it this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403390/select-records-from-start-of-month-to-current-date

Comment: Query should be the same – `SELECT … AND a.date >= :firstDay AND <= :now` and parameter for _first day of month_ `new \DateTime('1.' . date('m.Y'))` and for _first day of year_ `new \DateTime('1.1.' . date('Y'))`

Answer (score 9):

You have to remember that DQL is not SQL. The error comes from Doctrine's Lexer and not from MySQL. DQL doesn't support INTERVAL (see [list of supported functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)).

Read more on [adding your own functions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html), specifically adding DATE_ADD with INTERVAL support here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#date-add