# How to filter a query result based on a date time column in symfony2 DQL

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a query similar to this :

```
$em->createQuery(
    'SELECT t FROM myTestBundle:User t WHERE t.userId = :username AND
    t.tokenCreatedtime > (NOW() - INTERVAL 800 MINUTE)'
);
```

`(NOW() - INTERVAL 800 MINUTE)` is not working in DQL. Is there any other way that i can achieve this?

Comment: Achieve *what* specifically? As the DQL is not correct, it's also not clear what you want to do. Also which errro are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [INTERVAL 1 MONTH not working With symfony2 doctrine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041513/interval-1-month-not-working-with-symfony2-doctrine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to create a placeholder and pass the `DateTime` object

```
$q = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT t FROM myTestBundle:User t WHERE t.userId = :username AND
    t.tokenCreatedtime > :createdTime '
);
$q->setParameter(':createdTime',new \DateTime("-800 minute")
```

Also you might want to create the `\DateTime` Object as `new \DateTime("-800 minute")`