# Select records from start of month to current date using Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am having 2 issues with fetching data from doctrine:

1. Select records from start of month to current date
2. Select records from start of year to current date

How can I write a Doctrine queries to do the same thing as we do [in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403390/select-records-from-start-of-month-to-current-date)

Here is my incomplete code from my repository?

```
public function findByYearlyAttendanceTillToday($id)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT count(a) FROM CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance a where a.present LIKE 'A' and a.student_id = :id and a.date > :date");
    $query->setParameter('id', $id);
    $query->setParameter('date', **?????**);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
new \DateTime('midnight first day of this month');
new \DateTime('first day of january');
```

I would also change this:

```
a.date > :date
```

to this:

```
a.date >= :date
```

Comment: Great.. It Worked.. Can u please let me know any reference from where i can read all other arguments that i can pass through new \DateTime('');

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, but I couldn't find 'midnight first day of this month' argument anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159598/displaying-json-data-in-my-twig-template-in-symfony2 Can you please look at it

Comment: `new \DateTime('first day of today')` is a short alternative to `new \DateTime('midnight first day of this month')`.