# Displaying JSON Data in my Twig template in symfony2

Tags: json, symfony

I am trying to use a jquery extension as [Event calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my application. I tried it first with core php and it works fine. Now I want to use it in my symfony2 application, but i am not able to display it in my twig file. Here is my code i am using to render but i am not sure where i am doing it incorrect.

### Controller

```
public function studentCalendarAction()
{
  $year = date('Y');
  $month = date('m');
  $response = new Response(json_encode(array(
        array(
                'id' => 111,
                'title' => "Event1",
                'start' => "$year-$month-10",
                'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
        ),
  )));
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return $this->render('CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance:calendar.html.twig',array('response'=>$response));
}
```

### Router

```
CollegeStudentBundle_attendance_calendar:
    pattern:  /student/attendance/calendar
    defaults: { _controller: CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance:studentCalendar }
    requirements:
        _method:  GET|POST
```

### TWIG

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

                $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                    editable: true,

                    events: "../../student/attendance/calendar",

                    eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                        alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                            '(should probably update your database)');
                    },

                    loading: function(bool) {
                        if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                        else $('#loading').hide();
                    }

                });

            });

    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

Even I tried to make my `Router` like this

```
CollegeStudentBundle_attendance_calendar:
    pattern:  /student/attendance/calendar
    defaults: { _controller: CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance:studentCalendar, _format: json }
    requirements: { _format: (xml|json), _method: GET }
```

But this displays the code of twig file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the created `$response`, not the rendered response.

**Edit:**  Your revised `studentCalendarAction` would be,

```
public function studentCalendarAction()
{
  $year = date('Y');
  $month = date('m');

  $jsonData = json_encode(array(
        array(
                'id' => 111,
                'title' => "Event1",
                'start' => "$year-$month-10",
                'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
        ),
  ));

  $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  );

  $response = new Response($jsonData, 200, $headers);
  return $response;
}
```

Also I am assmuing that the twig file is rendered from different route, not `CollegeStudentBundle_attendance_calendar` route.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. can u please elobrate ur answer. where exactly i need to do the change. the controller, or the view.

Comment: In `studentCalenderAction` method of the controller. The rendering return is just another new `Response` object after parsing the twig file. Not the `Response` object you created with the json encoded array.

Comment: return new JsonResponse(array('id' => 111,...)); can be helpful, without forgetting use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;